# only retain lines with first instance of pattern, for multiple patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file here with many lines and  a number of columns, and I would like to keep lines only that have the first occurrence of a pattern/string, but for any repeated string/pattern in that column.

e.g.

```
cat exp.txt 
POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER 
182     3_12    G       A       .       PASS
192     3_22    A       A       .       PASS
199     4_22    G       A       .       PASS
201     10_22    A      A       .       PASS
214     10_35    A      G       .       PASS 
220     10_41    C      T       .       PASS
etc......
```

And I would like to remove lines that have the same starting ID (in the ID column), up to the "_" character...

e.g. (after script run)

```
cat post.exp.txt
POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER 
182     3_12    G       A       .       PASS
199     4_22    G       A       .       PASS
201     10_22    A      A       .       PASS
```

I am not sure how to approach due to the the fact that I want to remove lines with the subsequent occurrence(s) of any pattern (up to the _ character) in the ID column, not just a particular pattern.  Is this even possible?

Thanks -
LP

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!a[$2]++' FS='[ _]*' exp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative array to hold keys that have already been seen:

```
{
    if (split($2, a, /_/) > 0 )
    {
        key = a[1]
        if (!value[key])
        {
            value[key] = 1
            print $0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
$ cat exp.txt
POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER
182     3_12    G       A       .       PASS
192     3_22    A       A       .       PASS
199     4_22    G       A       .       PASS
201     10_22    A      A       .       PASS
214     10_35    A      G       .       PASS
220     10_41    C      T       .       PASS

$  awk ' { split($2,t,"_"); if( ! a[t[1]] ) { print ; a[t[1]]++ } }' exp.txt
POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER
182     3_12    G       A       .       PASS
199     4_22    G       A       .       PASS
201     10_22    A      A       .       PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

if `_` is not used in the first field William Pursell's answer is the best, if not, same concept applied after splitting the second field.  Note that if there are no `_` in the field the whole value will be used.

```
$ awk '{split($2,p,"_")} !a[p[1]]++' file

POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER 
182     3_12    G       A       .       PASS
199     4_22    G       A       .       PASS
201     10_22    A      A       .       PASS
```

Comment: can be shortened further ````awk ' split($2,p,"_") && ! a[p[1]]++ ' exp.txt````

Comment: My solution is the code golf winner, but I'm not sure it's "best".  A bit too obscure, really.

Answer (score 0):

Perl

```
$ perl -lane ' $F[1]=~/(.+)_/; print unless $kv{$1}++ ' exp.txt
POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER
182     3_12    G       A       .       PASS
199     4_22    G       A       .       PASS
201     10_22    A      A       .       PASS
```